# Define $h: \Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ by $h(x) = 2x + 1$. Is $h$ one-to-one? Why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Every rational number is different. x2 of every rational num will also be different. Add one to all sorts of different numbers, will yield a different number. Hence, I think it is one-to-one. Where am I wrong?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

Note that to show a function is one-to-one, normally we assume $f(x)=f(y)$ and show that $x=y.$

In this case$$2x+1=2y+1 \implies x=y$$ therefore it is one-to-one.

Intuitively you can see that your function is strictly increasing so it is one-to-one.

Or you can look at the graph which is a linear dust and it is one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Recall the definition of *one to one function*: Let $x,y\in\Bbb Q$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$. Can you prove that $x=y$ using simple algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then:
$$
y=2x+1 \implies x=\frac{y-1}{2} \in\mathbb{Q}
$$
Hence, $Im(f)=\mathbb{Q}$ and $f$ is surjective. 
Let $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{Q}, x_1 \neq x_2$. Then: 
$$
f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies \\
2x_1+1=2x_2+1 \implies \\
2(x_1-x_2)=0 \implies \\
x_1=x_2
 $$
There exists no different $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Therefore, the function is injective.
Since it is surjective and injective, it is bijective (also called one-to-one).